# Qt - Q_OBJECT causes undefined reference to vtable

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following class:

```
class MySqlTableModel : public QSqlRelationalTableModel
{
    //Q_OBJECT

public:
    MySqlTableModel();

    QSqlQuery add;
    QSqlQuery login;
    QSqlQuery logout;

    void addUser(QString text);
    virtual Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    bool adding = false;

public slots:
    void loginSlot();
    void logoutSlot();
};
```

Which derives from `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. I want to use some extra slots. My issue is, that if I comment the `Q_OBJECT` tag out, the slots are not recognized, and not connected(`QObject::connect: No such slot QSqlRelationalTableModel::MySqlTableModel::loginSlot()`). If I add the `Q_OBJECT` tag, however, I get an error: `/mysqltablemodel.cpp:5: error: undefined reference to vtable for MySqlTableModel'`, marking my constructor:

```
MySqlTableModel::MySqlTableModel()
{
}
```

[EDIT]
Running qmake solved the compile error, but connect still doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: Try running qmake.

Comment: What build system are you using? Is it set up correctly for calling the moc over your classes? If you are using qmake, run it again.

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator, I've tried compiling multiple times.

Comment: Select `Build` => `Run qmake` from the menubar.

Comment: Thanks, now I don't get the compile error, but it still cannot find the slots. What am I missing?

Comment: Oops, yes, duplicate. Deleted my answer. Indeed, you need to do "Build->Run qmake" every time you add `Q_OBJECT` somewhere.

Comment: qmake isn't exactly the most solid build system out there. If your slots can't be found, make sure to do a full clean/rebuild and see if the issue persists. Also, avoid using `SIGNAL()/SLOT()` syntax. Instead, use the modern syntax: `connect(srcObject, &ClassName::signalName, targetObj, &ClassName::slotName)` (note: `signalName` and `slotName` don't have `()`, they're function pointers.) With this syntax, your signal/slot connections are checked at compile time, not at run time. Also, `slotName` can be any function or lambda, it does not have to be a slot.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Okay, I'll keep that in mind.